# Why does my irFFT function have a small discrepancy distributed through the entire output?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python, numpy

Since I've last posted on dsp@stackexchange, I have been working on my algorithms and recently came across a useful radix-2 implementation which delivers performance as good or better than that of numpy's fft, as long as it is used with a fixed input(which is always the case for my work. I adapted it and unrolled it and went through a development cycle with chatgpt4.0 and the internet and I got it to give me results within a error rate of 1e-11 or better- except when it comes time to reverse the transform.  Skip to bottom for problem details.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba

tw = [np.exp(-1 * 1j * np.pi * np.arange(((2**i)//2), dtype=np.complex256) / ((2**i)//2)) for i in range(1,10)]
list_of_lists = [list(map(lambda x: [x.astype(np.complex128)], arr)) for arr in tw]
twiddlefactors = np.concatenate(list_of_lists)
inverse = np.conj(twiddlefactors)

    
@numba.jit(numba.float64[:](numba.complex128[:],numba.complex128[:,:]),fastmath=True,nopython=True)
def optimized_numba_irfft_v(n:np.ndarray, tf: np.ndarray):
    #danger! do not use this function yet. the reconstruction error is greater than 1e-5!

    N = 512
    #this function has been constrained to only work on compex data(complex128), power of two +1 arrays of size 257, and only returns 512 elements.
    #the handling is not exactly identical to numpy rfft, but is pretty close.
    #Consult https://github.com/ChangWeiTan/MultiRocket/blob/3ccaa4f8ed11769b904af885e17018c39c89a2ac/utils/tools.py#L10 for the original function

    

    # Pre-calculation of the matrix M
    M = np.asarray([[1.+0.0000000e+00j, 1.+0.0000000e+00j],[ 1.+0.0000000e+00j, -1.+1.2246468e-16j]],dtype=np.complex128) #for irfft
     
    #perform the fixed extraction
    
    nFFT = 512
    x = np.zeros(512, dtype=np.complex128)
    x[:256] = n[:-1]
    nyquist = n[-1].real #retrieve the nyquist component


    #original code
    # X_stage = np.zeros((512, 256), dtype=np.complex128)
    # X_stage[:2, :256] = np.dot(M, x.reshape((2, -1)))

      #for i in range(1, 9): 

      #q = 2**(8-(i-1)) //2
      #e = 2**i
      
      #X_even = X_stage[:e, :q].copy()
      #X_odd = X_stage[:e, q:2*q].copy()
      #X_stage[:e, :q] = X_even + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] *X_odd
      #X_stage[e:e*2, :q] = X_even - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_odd

    #return X_stage[:N//2 + 1,0]

    X_stage_0 = np.zeros((2, 256), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_1 = np.zeros((4, 128), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_2 = np.zeros((8, 64), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_3 = np.zeros((16, 32), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_4 = np.zeros((32, 16), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_5 = np.zeros((64, 8), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_6 = np.zeros((128, 4), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_7 = np.zeros((256, 2), dtype=np.complex128)
    X_stage_8 = np.zeros((512, 1), dtype=np.complex128)

    #perform the initial identity transfer and unraveling
    X_stage_0[0, :] = M[0, 0] * x[:256]  + M[0, 1] * x[256:]
    X_stage_0[1, :] = M[1, 0] * x[:256]  + M[1, 1] * x[256:]

    e = 2
    q = 128
    X_stage_1[:e, :q] = X_stage_0[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_0[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_1[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_0[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_0[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 4
    q = 64
    X_stage_2[:e, :q] = X_stage_1[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_1[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_2[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_1[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_1[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 8
    q = 32
    X_stage_3[:e, :q] = X_stage_2[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_2[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_3[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_2[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_2[:e, q:2*q]
    
    e = 16
    q = 16
    X_stage_4[:e, :q] = X_stage_3[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_3[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_4[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_3[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_3[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 32
    q = 8
    X_stage_5[:e, :q] = X_stage_4[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_4[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_5[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_4[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_4[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 64
    q = 4
    X_stage_6[:e, :q] = X_stage_5[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_5[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_6[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_5[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_5[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 128
    q = 2
    X_stage_7[:e, :q] = X_stage_6[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_6[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_7[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_6[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_6[:e, q:2*q]

    e = 256
    q = 1
    X_stage_8[:e, :q] = X_stage_7[:e, :q] + tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1] * X_stage_7[:e, q:2*q]
    X_stage_8[e:e*2, :q] = X_stage_7[:e, :q] - tf[(e-1):(2*e)-1]  *  X_stage_7[:e, q:2*q]
    
    result = X_stage_8.real.flatten() /256.0#
    result[:] +=  (nyquist / 256.0)  # add the Nyquist frequency to all time points
    return result
```

now, when demonstrating/testing this on any example data alongside numpy's fft library, my rfft function gives very similar results(better than 1e-10) but the inverse rfft does not. Instead there is an oscillating component distributed through the entire product of approximately 0.0004 peak to peak. the problem here is that my inverting function is just my forward function with a few things changed- the twiddlefactors, the last component of M, and the addition of the nyquist handling and the division.

I have ruled out this coming from the rfft and through the rest of the code by exchanging components and using other libraries to make sure my results are good. Could someone take a look?

I have extracted the error component and run it through numpy.fft.rfft
[image: pyplot image of error components]

Comment: What's the frequency of the error? Is is always the same? What test signals did you sue ? What do you get with sine waves, unit impulses, white noise, etc ?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uDVG9JU6Jekv2Gb4LpAvvlTybyhKvhWL#scrollTo=PA5xTYH8-Mnd

you're welcome to examine my testing methodology as well as my code.

Comment: Looks like your problem is related to the first few frequencies of the spectrum. However, this is a huge pile of code to read.  You may have better luck isolating the problem in a single unit test with as little extra code around it as possible. Try a bunch of simple test signals first, where you already know the correct answer and step through code to see where it goes wrong. Try DC only, only one bin at a time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use another approach and chatgpt to identify the problem: the problem is that i didn't exploit the symmetry.

```py
    ...
    n_full = np.concatenate([n, np.conj(n[-2:0:-1])])

    #perform the initial identity transfer and unraveling.
    X_stage_0[0, :] = M[0, 0] * n_full[:256]  + M[0, 1] * n_full[256:]
    X_stage_0[1, :] = M[1, 0] * n_full[:256]  + M[1, 1] * n_full[256:]
    ....
```

with these changes, the code now works as expected